# Unit test , large setups/fixtures

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

Lets say we have a `Service` with other servcies on `DI`. The method under test does somehting with the input data, does some validations, calls a couple of these injected services (can get data only or modify data and then return something) and then returns something.

Given this scenario, I need to write many cases testing all possible behaviors, like validations exceptions, not found exceptions, business exceptions, normal flow, etc...

The problem is that I need to mock all the methods on an injected service for the setup. This could grow fast.

**What's the best approach for fixtures and setups (mocking dependencies) in this large/complex method? Is there a pattern that solves this?**

For data mocking I use `builder pattern` wich simplifies the task very well.

Comment: It seems method is doing too much. Split it into multiple testable methods.

Comment: When you have many dependencies you surely need many mocks for them. That´s why you should keep your unit under test small.

Comment: @Sinatr that may be true. But not all methods are splitable. Also, if the split is done, what about testing the "orchestator" method that calls those smaller methods?

Answer (score 1):

You should try create independent classes, which you could test without introducing too many dependencies, but in some point there will be a class which uses other components(for example ViewModel). In such cases I use:
https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture

It helps in creation system/class under test and helps with injecting dependencies. You can use it with NSubstitute but not only with it.

Using AutoFixture you can create mock classes which you will examine, but rest dependencies which will be not needed AutoFixture will auto-generate for you, so extending a constructor will not lead to modifying bunch of unit tests.